# Context sensitive logging with postsharp

Tags: postsharp

I have a formula engine which compiles C# code and then runs it. The C# code does contain methods, which are implemented in the base class of the newly created and compiled class.

The formulas which are compiled can be administered by non developers. Until now, that works well. Sometimes it happens that the business implements formulas which are forcing the system to hang by using endless loops over two or more signals.

Because of the compilation system, i can not get the call tree of the methods that are called and how and when.

My idea was to develop a PostSharp which logs the call tree of the methods.

My problem is now to find the context where the current method was called. Which means, which method was calling the current method. Is there a way to find out the calling method and instance of the current method in the MethodBoundaryAspect?

Comment: After searching the web again I found a hint by myself. Use Stackframe to get the call tree of the current request and use this to find out the context where the current method was called.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're going to log only the current method for each method call, then the log will display the correctly ordered tree of method calls.